# Can't uninstall or reinstall WhatsApp on Windows PC

Tags: windows-10, whatsapp

I have a problem installing WhatsApp on my Windows 10 PC, and I can't even uninstall the app too, the message for when I try to uninstall is:

> The code execution can't continue because ffmpeg.dll wasn't found. Reinstalling the program to fix the problem.

And whenever I try to install the app it says:

> There was an error while installing the application. Check the setup log for more information and contact the author.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Please provide the setup log for WhatsApp, we will be unable to help you unless you provide this log.

Answer (score 0):

Delete whatsapp folder from C:/Program Files and use C-cleaner or other registry cleaner to delete registry entries and files related to whatsapp. Then try to re-install program. If same issue continue then you need to fix missing dll or might need to repair your window

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have a genuine download source for WhatsApp? The error message "*Reinstalling the program to fix the problem*" is so far from correct English that it raises questions about what you're trying to install. Where did you get this from?